# How to write test case for destroy method in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

```
#Destroy Action method
def destroy
  Key.destroy(params[:id])
end
-------------------------------
#testcase for this
 expect(delete :destroy ,{"id"=>"3"}).to change(Key, :count).by(-1)
```

It is showing Action view::template missing error can't I write test case for void action(returns nothing/render nothing) methods in rails.

Now i changed my method to render the json value.

```
def destroy
  Key.destroy(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {}
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end
```

Now my assertion for to run test case is:

```
it "should destroy" do
   response=delete :destroy ,{"id"=>"3"}
   expect(response).to have_http_status(204)
end
```

Comment: **Be specific with your errors.** Include the full error here.  Also, how you're setting up the RSpec assertion would help too.  Further to that, the fact that if you allow an entity to be destroyed, logically it'd make sense to redirect to the standard show action, in case the entity destroyed was the one a user was interfacing with.

Comment: your action *doesn't* "render nothing" - that's the point of the error.

Comment: I Know the error but i tried to write for the above destroy function. But i realized it must give some response from controller action.At the end i render "format.json { head :no_content }" if successfully deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a sample item with a Factory (for example Factory Girl) and then check if it exists or not. This is a sample destroy test (the query is for a Mongoid db instead, but you can get it. 
In my case, my destroy method has a json response which can be checked as well (but I don't do it here).

```
   let(:key_to_delete) {FactoryGirl.create(:key)}

   it 'should destroy' do
      delete :destroy, id: key_to_delete.id
      expect(Key.where(id: key_to_delete.id).count).to eq(0)
    end
```

Comment: There is no problem with My first  assertion .But the controller action must return something in response as you are returning json response. this is a reason for  Actionview::template missing error.

Comment: I see. Then your updated destroy action looks fine. If you don't want to reload the page, you have to use ajax and check the json response from controller. This goes beyond your test, you need to explain what do you want to do when you destroy the item (reload, go to index, etc).